# Re Load a Form when click on other form

Tags: c#, windows

I have a form "A" Opened in the Parent form "P" . THe Form A have datagridview - when click on the content it will open a new form as Popup ( let that form be "B")
My requirement is to refresh the datagridview content in "A" on clicking a button in Form "B".
The datagridview in "A" contains a Product list. When Click content opens delete page. When deleting - i have to refresh the grid view. How it is possible ?

Comment: Be more specific, or write few lines of your code so that your problem can be understood.

Comment: after deleting the data you have to call your grid view bind method again so that this time it will take only the undeleted value.

Comment: Thanx Mr.Rahul.Scenario : I have a Windows Form Called Manage Product . That is opened with main form as its parent. The Manage Product Contains all the products from database. When click on the Name of the product in datagridview (CellContent Click Event) it will open anthoer form called Edit Product. it has two button one is update and other delete. What ever i have done in this form for that particular product, it has to be reflected in the ManageProduct gridview.I have called the bind method again. But no use. it is not reflecting.Please note that i am not closing the manage product form.

Answer (score 0):

To refresh your grid view when you delete a row you need to call your DataGridView datasource event again like

```
DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True;
DataGridView1.DataSource = ds; // dataset
DataGridView1.DataMember = "TableName"; // table name you need to show
```

This will bind your DataGridView again with undeleted records.You have to do something like that.

**Related to Your Problem**

> You need to Put all your initialization code into a method and not the
>   constructor or the Form Load event and just call that method. This can
>   also include the designer-generated InitializeComponent() method which
>   sets up all controls on the form. You should remove all controls on
>   the form as your first action in that method, though.When ever you
>   want to load it again call that particular method again.It will reload
>   your page again.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanx Mr.Rahul.Scenario : I have a Windows Form Called Manage Product . That is opened with main form as its parent. The Manage Product Contains all the products from database. When click on the Name of the product in datagridview (CellContent Click Event) it will open anthoer form called Edit Product. it has two button one is update and other delete. What ever i have done in this form for that particular product, it has to be reflected in the ManageProduct gridview.I have called the bind method again. But no use. it is not reflecting.Please note that i am not closing the manage product form

Comment: after deleting you need to call your DataGridView binding event in Manage Product or in Edit Product.

Comment: Sorry Rahul. I didnt get you. can you juse provide a bit of code here.

Comment: dear i have given you the whole scenarion that how to work.now it's your understanding.try to understand my logic.

Answer (score -1):

When you click Button in Form B,open form A by

```
A a=new A();

   a.Show();
```

In Form_Load Event of Form A Just Rebind the datagridview

For Any Changes Made to a grid if you want the changes to get reflected then you have to rebind the grid and write

```
datagridview.DataBind();
```

Comment: This is for WinForm /Windows. Not ASP.Net